# gcd of numbers from $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}] $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying this problem:

**Find the maximum common divisor (in $ \mathbb{Z} $) of the numbers $ a, \ b $ such that $ (1 + \sqrt{5})^{2020} = a + b \sqrt{5} $.**

Taking norms (the context is the ring $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}] $), we have:
$$
N(1 + \sqrt{5}) = 1^2 - 5 \cdot 1^2 = -4
$$
and then, if $ d = mcd(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z} $,
$$
N(d) = d^2 \mid (-4)^{2020} = 2^{4040}
$$
So, $ d $ must be $ 1 $ or a power of two. But I am stuck now. I have tried more things unsuccessfully. By inspection:
$$
(1 + \sqrt{5})^2 = 6 + 2 \sqrt{5} \longrightarrow d = 2
$$
$$
(1 + \sqrt{5})^3 = 16 + 8 \sqrt{5} \longrightarrow d = 2^3
$$
$$
(1 + \sqrt{5})^4 = 56 + 24 \sqrt{5} \longrightarrow d = 2^3
$$
$$
(1 + \sqrt{5})^5 = 176 + 80 \sqrt{5} \longrightarrow d = 2^4
$$
$$
(1 + \sqrt{5})^6 = 576 + 256 \sqrt{5} \longrightarrow d = 2^6
$$
I can't clear see a pattern here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}=\varphi$$
$$(1+\sqrt5)^{2020}=2^{2020}\varphi^{2020}$$
As is well known, $\varphi^n=f_n\varphi+f_{n-1}$, where $f_n$ is the Fibbonachi sequence.
$$2^{2020}\varphi^{2020}=2^{2020}(f_{2020}\varphi+f_{2019})=2^{2020}\frac{f_{2020}\sqrt5+f_{2020}+2f_{2019}}{2}$$
$$\gcd(a,b)=2^{2019}gcd(f_{2020},f_{2020}+2f_{2019})$$
We note the Fibbonachi sequence is 3-periodic modolu 2 where $f_1\equiv1$.
thus, $f_{2020}$ is odd and since the $\gcd$ is a power of $2$,
$$gcd(a,b)=2^{2019}$$